# Download all images of PWA into cache from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, storage

There is a PWA based on vuejs, which is connected to firebase.

The app has several pages with images. Each page has several images – to see all images on the page you need to scroll down the page. All images are stored on firebase storage.
When you scroll down the page at the first moment images are not displayed because the app downloads them. After a few seconds images appear.

The **task** is to avoid the downloading of the images during scroll down the page and display the images immediately during the scroll.

At this moment:

- all images are uploaded to the firebase storage with the following metadata: metadata = { cacheControl: 'public, max-age=300000000, s-maxage=300000000' }
- when the image is downloaded it appears in the app cache. When you scroll down all pages – all images are in the app cache. In this case all images are displayed immediately during the scroll.
- When you refresh the page - all images are deleted from the cache.

To resolve the task my suggestion is to download all images into cache when you open PWA. And it is desirable to download images into cache for the next 3 days.

Please, help me **find the way to download all images into cache for the next 3 days at the point you open the PWA**.

Or if my suggestion is not the best way to resolve the task – please, advice better way to solve the task.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could share some code with us. Especially how your Service Worker (SW) is working.

There are multiple points you should consider:

Every SW has a lifecycle and some of them are set to clear the cache on the Lifescyle event "Activated". Check if yours is doing that.

One thing you should do is catch all GET request to the images and return them from cache if they are there and from server if not (this should be done in the SW)

You can store thenm in the SW while he is getting installed. Just make sure not to save to much at once because the installation could faill very easy then.

Try to save them in smaller batches to the cache as you scroll down in advance and in a async way. You can save data to the cache also from the front end code.

Comment: Thank you Tarik for your answer. At the moment I do not use SW yet. But as I understand firebase widget emulates something like SW. That is why after image is displayed/dowloaded from the storage, this image is cached in browser. After image cached, the image is displayed immediatly during scrolling the page. Is the way to download and cache all images at the start of using the PWA?